# ubuntu software store doesn't work not booting

Tags: software-center

Ubuntu software store isn't working after upgrading to 17. I followed instructions here http://www.ubuntuupdates.com/2017/05/fix-ubuntu-software-center-not-working.html  but it didn't resolve my problem. Any help would be appreciated. -Jimbo

Comment: That guide was probably written by an idiot. All you need to do is to fully update your system. Please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: No success with your suggestion. Sigh.